# host a SQLite .db file on dropbox.com

Tags: java, sqlite, dropbox, sqlitejdbc

First of all, can anybody tell me if Dropbox.com has write access.

if so then how would you access an SQLite .db file hosted there within your Java applet

specs:

```
I'm using Eclipse Helios
Using David Crawshaw's SQLite jdbc driver (v. 056)
```

not sure what other info you might need, if you need more info then leave a comment.

Comment: nevermind, I was trying to do something which I could not as pointed out by Doug. I created my own work around though and will breifly explain it for anyone who is still interested in this.

Comment: though you can not do this on dropbox, a loophole is that you can create a googlesite with the filelocker format, you then add the db file to your dropbox. now using the Google sites API you can make your applet download the db file. you then edit or do whatever with it in your program. if you edit it you then update the file with the new one. and now to prevent future errors in your program you delete the file that you downloaded (using code in program) (all this stuff is documented in the API for the Google sites and all jars are there to download) anyway, yes this is prob. bad to do, ItWork

Comment: sorry bout bad grammer at end, out of space and wanted to keep post together.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share a writable SQLite database via Dropbox. SQLite needs file system access to the database file for all applications that read or write the file.

Comment: do you know of any other free hosting site which i could do this on???

Comment: Do what? There are lots of free hosting sites, but none that provide the file access that SQLite requires. SQLite is not a database server. You need to rethink your requirements, or express them more clearly.

Comment: basically what i need this to do is in an applet (embedded on an html page) have this allow the applet to read the sqlite database which is hosted online, changes will be made to this database from an application on a different computer that is created with AdobeAir

Comment: So, the we applet only reads; it does not write the database. Are the changes made from AdobeAir concurrent with the operation of the web server? Where is the AdobeAir app running relative to the web server? On the same local network?

Comment: currently within our company which is developing this system the applet and application are on the same network, but i beleive that the intention is for these to be able to be on seperate networks as well, as i'm only developing the applet part, and the person developing the adobeAIR app is out for this week i do not have all the information.